# Need help with a company's name that involves a surname

Tags: surnames

If it's a trading company's name which one is correct?

> LEE TRADING or LEE'S TRADING

Where Lee is a Chinese surname.

Comment: Company names (or the names of anything else) can be anything you like.

Comment: Also free to use **Trader Lee**, as Joe might suggest.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever sounds best. It's called Bush's Beans because some might find Bush Beans  off-putting. On the other hand, it's just Heinz ketchup, since Heinz's would be a mouthful. In this particular case, there isn't much reason to prefer either style.

Comment: I'd like "Ben's and Jerry" :)